# SendMessage c++

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

i was making a program and i need a functiong SendMessage to simulate a key press in a game window, but i don't understood how i can use this function:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL,"Game");
        HWND edit = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, "Edit", NULL);
        SendMessage(edit, WM_CHAR, (TCHAR) 'H', 0);
        SendMessage(edit, WM_CHAR, (TCHAR) 'L', 0);
        SendMessage(edit, WM_CHAR, (TCHAR) 'O', 0);
}
```

in "Game" and "Edit" there are this error :

```
Error: l'argomento di tipo "const char *" è incompatibile con il parametro di tipo "LPCWSTR"
```

Comment: Error message in English: `the argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it's obvious that you are compiling your application as UNICODE. With that in mind:

`"Edit"` is not a 16bit WIDE string, it's an 8bit NARROW string, and `CreateWindow` expects a WIDE string when compiling in UNICODE. Use `TEXT("Edit")` or `L"Edit"` instead. Same with `"Game"`.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand how use it, could give me an example of code?

Answer (score 0):

You have "Use Unicode Character Set" in "Character Set" of Configuration Properties -> General og project properties. That's why almost all WinAPI functions that have a dial with text has W at the end of name. So you can fix this in several ways:

1. Change Character Set to Use Multi-Byte Character Set
2. Use FindWindowA and FindWindowExA and SendMessageA
3. Add tchar.h header file and use _T("Game") and so on macro

Comment: Use `TEXT("Game")` instead of `_T("Game")`.  The `TEXT()` macro belongs to the Win32 API and is used with `TCHAR`.  The `_T()` macro belongs to the C runtime and is used with `_TCHAR`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yeah, I know that names with underscore is C/C++ extensions, but I never see that, for example, _TCHAR was not TCHAR. It depends on _UNICODE, but UNICODE and _UNICODE is always defined together. If not - something very bad with your code. But, generally you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is complaining about `LPCWSTR` means your project is being compiling with Unicode enabled (`UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are being defined during the preprocessor stage).  That means the `TCHAR` versions of `FindWindow(Ex)()` are mapping to `FindWindow(Ex)W()` which expect `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`) parameters, instead of to `FindWindow(Ex)A()` which expect `LPSTR` (`char*`) parameters.

`"Game"` and `"Edit"` are character string literals without any specifiers attached to them, so they are interpreted by the compiler as `const char[]`.  A `char[]` can degrade into a `char*`, but it cannot be passed where a `wchar_t*` is expected.  That is why you are getting the error.

So you have a few choices:

1. disable Unicode in your project settings, then the code you showed will compile as-is.
2. when using `TCHAR` versions of functions, you should wrap literals with the `TEXT()` macro to make them be interpreted as `const wchar_t[]` or `const char[]` depending on whether Unicode is enabled or not:

   ```
   HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("Game"));
   HWND edit = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, TEXT("Edit"), NULL);
   ```
3. stop using the `TCHAR` versions of `FindWindow(Ex)()` altogether.  Use `FindWindow(Ex)A()` or `FindWindow(Ex)W()` directly instead:

   ```
   HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Game");
   HWND edit = FindWindowExA(hWnd, NULL, "Edit", NULL);
   ```

   ```
   HWND hWnd = FindWindowW(NULL, L"Game");
   HWND edit = FindWindowExW(hWnd, NULL, L"Edit", NULL);
   ```